# Is there a simpler way that this to get each element of a sequence, paired with "its" tail?

Tags: clojure

I find myself needing to convert a sequence of elements, to a sequence of "pairs", the first element of  which is the element of the initial sequence, and the second element of while is the tail of the initial sequence from that element.

> (a b c d e) -> ((a (b c d e)) (b (c d e)) (c (d e)) (d (e)) (e ()))

I wrote this:

```
(defn head-and-tail [s]
  (cond (empty? s) ()
    :else (cons (list (first s) (rest s)) (head-and-tail (rest s)))))
```

Is there is a built in function, or a simple combination of built in functions that can do this more easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
(let [xs [1 2 3 4]]
  (map list xs (iterate rest (rest xs))))
;= ((1 (2 3 4)) (2 (3 4)) (3 (4)) (4 ()))
```

This can of course be tweaked to suit your needs, for instance you might prefer `map vector` to `map list` etc.

Also, about the `head-and-tail` impl from the question text: the two-way-branching `cond` would be better written as an `if`.

Comment: Thanks Michal, very edifying.